# Google Maps Api: Polyline editable events - Make a vertex non-editable

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polyline, vertex

I want to make the starting and ending vertex of an editable polyline non-editable. So that users can edit all other vertexes except those two. I have implemented an event listener (mousedown) to filter the vertex but how can I stop it from being editable.?

```
google.maps.event.addListener(poly, 'mousedown', function (event) {
    if (event.vertex === 0) { // First vertex of polyline
        //disable vertex from being editable
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right path.

To detect a vertex has been moved, you listen to the `set_at` event on the Polyline's Path. However, this won't let you know what was the original position, so what I'd do is capture the `mousedown` event, just as you said, and declare an `addListenerOnce` on the `set_at` event of the Path to reset the vertex coords if I'm on the first or last point.

**The following listener will allow the user to drag those vertices, but they'll subborntly go back to they original position:**

```
google.maps.event.addListener(poly, 'mousedown', function (event) {
    var thePath = this.getPath();
    if (event.vertex === 0 || event.vertex === thePath.getLength() - 1) {
        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(thePath, 'set_at', function (vertex) {
            this.setAt(vertex, event.latLng);
        });
    }
});
```

Why am I using `addListenerOnce`? You see, that's because otherwise the very act of resetting the first or last points would trigger that same event, leading to an max stack error.

**Edit: here's another shot at it. The following listener won't allow the user to drag said vertices**. However, I'm re-enabling the editable behavior inmediatly. There might be a race condition in your browser.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(poly, 'mousedown', function (event) {
    var thePath = this.getPath();

    if (event.vertex === 0 || event.vertex === thePath.getLength() - 1) {
        console.debug('Vertex forbidden!');
        this.set('editable',false);
        this.set('editable',true);
    } 
});
```

Comment: Ok, but is there no way to disable the move. To make the point stable?

Comment: Hey @StathisGaknis I added a second way to do it which perhaps is what you are looking for. Best of lucks.

Comment: Thank you kindly for both answers. I am looking for a solid solution (no race conditions ) so I will get back when I solve it. I do however believe that this should be handled by gmaps with an event or sth.

Comment: Don't get too picky. You just need to re-enable the editable setting inside a timeout, and that's if and only you ever get to notice a race condition that might not even be there.